# How to extract special characters from route in Zend framework 3

Tags: regex, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework3, zend-route

I'm sending a url that has special characters in them.

```
/contacts?advanceSearch=true&advanceSearchType=rating&advanceSearchValue=A1A+
```

As you see the variable value of `advanceSearchValue` is `A1A+`

But when I retrieve this in controller

```
$this->params()->fromQuery("advanceSearchValue");
```

it shows me `A1A`. It adds space instead of `+`

This is my route config.

```
"contacts"                   => [
            "type"                   => "segment",
            "options"                => [
                "route"              => "/contacts[/:action[/:id]]",

                "defaults"           => [
                    "controller"     => Controller\ContactController::class,
                    "action"         => "index",
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `+` has a special meaning in a URL and Zend knows this and correctly replaces it with a space.

To get a `+` character into the parsed data you need to URL escape it. This gives the value `%2B`.

So your full URL should be

```
/contacts?advanceSearch=true&advanceSearchType=rating&advanceSearchValue=A1A%2B
```

By the way, what is producing this URL, a web browser should be automatically converting the + character before sending it to the web server?

Comment: No, I'm sending it via AJAX

Comment: OK, my AJAX skill is limited, but I guess there is some method that will URI / URL escape the data before creating the link. Perhaps adding this info to the question and adding an Ajax tag will interest people with the correct skill set

Comment: This is the correct answer here. See [JavaScript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). You should encode the query string like `encodeURIComponent($queryString)` (`$queryString` something like: `?key=value+something`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your request-url :
You can encode it by php Or Javascript -

*In javascript :*

```
var url= "/contacts?advanceSearch=true&advanceSearchType=rating&advanceSearchValue=A1A+";
 url= encodeURI(uri);
```

*In php :*

```
$url = urlencode('/contacts?advanceSearch=true&advanceSearchType=rating&advanceSearchValue=A1A+');
```

Then use this encoded Url in your ajax.